# Передача в метод обобщенных интерфейсов

Tags: c#

Имеется такой код:

```
public interface IInterface<T>
{
    IDictionary<int, T> GetData();
}

public class Base
{        
}

public class A: Base
{        
}

public class B : Base
{
}

public class ADA: IInterface<A>
{
    public IDictionary<int, A> GetData()
    {
        return new Dictionary<int, A>(){ {0, new A() }};            
    }
}

public class BDA : IInterface<B>
{
    public IDictionary<int, B> GetData()
    {
        return new Dictionary<int, B>() { { 0, new B() } };
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Fill(params IInterface<T>[] @interface)
    {
        foreach (var access in @interface)
            access.GetData();
    }
}
```

Он не компилируется, вопрос такой: Как можно передать несколько реализаций интерфейса IInterface в метод Fill ? Есть разные способы, хочется узнать какой правильный. Если ошибка в проектировании, подскажите пожалуйста как будет верно ? Классы Base, A, B изменять нежелательно.

Comment: Предположим, что вы нашли способ это сделать. Что дальше будет происходить с результатом вызова access.GetData()? Ведь вы не знаете его тип. и в переменную сохранить не можете.

Comment: Мне там уже не важно знать тип. Его можно будет воспринимать как object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Т.к. строгой типизации все равно не получить, то есть несколько вариантов:

1. dynamic:

   ```
   public static void Fill(params dynamic[] interfaces) 
   {
       foreach (var access in interfaces)
       {
           object data = access.GetData();
       }
   }
   ```
2. dynamic с маркер-интерфейсом:

   ```
   public interface IInterface { }

   public interface IInterface<T> : IInterface
   {
       IDictionary<int, T> GetData();
   }

   public static void Fill(params IInterface[] interfaces) 
   {
       foreach (dynamic access in interfaces)
       {
           object data = access.GetData();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Реальный интерфейс с неявной реализацией в ADA и BDA

   ```
   public interface IInterface
   { 
       IDictionary GetData();
   }

   public interface IInterface<T> : IInterface
   {
       new IDictionary<int, T> GetData();
   }

   public class BDA : IInterface<B>
   {
       public IDictionary<int, B> GetData()
       {
           return new Dictionary<int, B>() { { 0, new B() } };
       }

       IDictionary IInterface.GetData()
       {
           return (IDictionary)this.GetData();
       }
   }

   public static void Fill(params IInterface[] interfaces) 
   {
       foreach (var access in interfaces)
       {
           IDictionary data = access.GetData();
       }
   }
   ```

В последнем случае типизация какая-никакая будет. В первых двух - object.